# How to set up an inductive proof in haskell?

Tags: haskell, proof, induction

I need to prove

```
f (g xs) == g (f xs)
```

whenver xs is a finite list of Ints.

Assume both f and g are of type [Int]->[Int]

Comment: This is for specific `f` and `g`, right? (For arbitrary `f` and `g` it does not hold.)

Comment: They are both  of type [Int]->[Int] and both take a finite integer list.

Answer (score 5):

Disproof by counterexample:

```
f xs = []
g xs = [1]
```

If you want this property to hold, you need more specific constraints on what `f` and `g` are.

You may be thinking of the law that

```
(map f . map g) == map (f . g)
```

which can indeed be proven.

Answer (score -1):

Found this from somewhere

```
Theorem: (map f . map g) xs = map (f . g) xs
       - Proof is by induction on xs
    *** Base Case, xs = []
        - Left side: (map f . map g) [] = map f (map g []) = map f [] = []
        - Right side: map (f . g) [] = []
    *** Inductive Case, xs = k:ks
        - Inductive Hypothesis: (map f . map g) ks = map (f . g) ks
        - Left Side
          + (map f . map g) xs
          + map f (map g (k:ks))
          + map f ((g k) : (map g ks))
          + (f (g k)) : (map f (map g ks))
          + ((f . g) k) : ((map f . map g) ks)  i.e. change from bracket form back to point form
          + ((f . g) k) : (map (f . g) ks) by inductive hypothesis
          + map (f . g) (k:ks) by definition of map
          + map (f . g) xs
```

Comment: This is very different than saying `f (g xs) == g (f xs)` which, as others have pointed out, is false in general.